# How can i put the datePicker info into my sql database?

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple program that insert a movie info into a database, the ID, title, and the date, however i can't put the date, i already tried some methods including the java docs but no one helped.

Here's my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package prueba3;

import connectivity.ConnectioClass;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import connectivity.DatabaseTableRowViewObject;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author Guillermo
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private TextField texto;
    @FXML
    private Button boton2;
    @FXML
    private TextField texto2;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker texto3;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DatabaseTableRowViewObject, Integer> id;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DatabaseTableRowViewObject, String> nombre;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DatabaseTableRowViewObject, String> fecha;
    
    @FXML
    private TableView<DatabaseTableRowViewObject> tabla;
    ObservableList<DatabaseTableRowViewObject> conexion;
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        label.setText(texto.getText());

        // added to make sure the properties of the object can be shown..
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        nombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stringy"));
        fecha.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fecha"));
        ConnectioClass connectioclass = new ConnectioClass();
        Connection Connection = connectioclass.getConnection();
        //String sql="INSERT INTO adios VALUES('"+texto.getText()+"')";
      
        String  pop = "INSERT INTO adios VALUES ('"+texto.getText()+"','" +texto2.getText()+"''" +texto3.getValue()+"')";
        //String paco = "INSERT INTO adios (nombre) VALUES('" +texto3.getText()+"')";
        
        Statement statement= Connection.createStatement();

        Statement f = Connection.createStatement();
        ConnectioClass.mostrar(f, tabla);

        //statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        Connection.createStatement();
        //statement.executeUpdate(paco);
                statement.executeUpdate(pop);
    }

    @FXML
    private void botoneliminar(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        label.setText(texto.getText());
        ConnectioClass connectioclass = new ConnectioClass();
        Connection Connection = connectioclass.getConnection();
        String sql="DELETE FROM adios WHERE nombre =('"+texto.getText()+"')";
        Statement statement= Connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
    }

    @FXML
    private void fechas(ActionEvent event){
        LocalDate fechas = texto3.getValue();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

As you can see, there's a date called "texto3", and `texto3.getValue()` is not working, so i don't know what to do to get my date picker work.

Any idea? Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [java.sql.PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than `java.sql.Statement`. You should also use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Your code for inserting into database table `adios` should be something like the following.

```java
String  pop = "INSERT INTO adios VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
ConnectioClass connectioclass = new ConnectioClass();
try (java.sql.Connection connection = connectioclass.getConnection();
     java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(pop)) {
    ps.setString(1, texto.getText());
    ps.setString(2, texto2.getText());
    java.sql.Date theDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(texto3.getValue());
    ps.setDate(3, theDate);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Method `getValue` of class [DatePicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm) returns [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Method `setDate` (in interface `PreparedStatement`) accepts a `java.sql.Date` parameter. Hence you need to convert `LocalDate` to `java.sql.Date`. Static method `valueOf` (in interface `java.sql.Date`) does the conversion for you.

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html